quantum espresso ESM relax calculation
Is it possible to relax a slab with ESM bc1 conditions in Quantum Espresso?
The slab has vacuum regions on each side in the z direction. The relaxation is performed on the z direction only. The x and y forced are kept at zero.
I try it and the energies just go bonkers after the first scf step. I am not sure this is an issue with my system or ESM is not compatible with relax.
